# type in term ~T cannot be a type parameter, but can be a slice referring to a type parameter

Tags: go, generics

```golang
func demo[S ~In, In, Out any](s S, in In, out Out) Out {
   return out
}
```

This function does not compile with the error:

> type in term ~In cannot be a type parameter：

But if I write `S` as a slice type, it compiles：

```golang
func demo[S ~[]In, In, Out any](s S, in In, out Out) Out {
   return out
}
```

I understand what `~` does is, if `type mytype int`, then the type of `In` is `mytype`, but the type of `S` can be int because `int` is the underlying type of `mytype`, I can't figure out why it has to be written as `S ~[]In`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From [type parameter proposal](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/HEAD/design/43651-type-parameters.md#approximation-constraint-element) under `Approximation constraint element` :

> Using ~T is not permitted if T is a type parameter or if T is an interface type.

[`any`](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin@go1.22.1#any) is an alias for `interface{}`.

The error message is better using `interface{}` directly.

```
invalid use of ~ (interface{} is an interface)
```

[go playground link](https://go.dev/play/p/W-J93wA7MKB)

---

The reason it works when using `~[]In` is it's essentially saying match whose underlying type is `[]any`.

For example,

```
type IntArr []int
func demo[T ~[]U, U any](arr T, val U){}

arr := IntArr{1, 2, 3}
demo(arr, 2) // Works fine.
```

This works because `IntArr`'s underlying type can be matched with `[]any`.

And using `~IntArr` is not valid. From the proposal earlier (emphasis mine)

> `~T` means the set of all types whose underlying type is `T`, **it will be an error to use `~T` with a type `T` whose underlying type is not itself**.

[go playground link](https://go.dev/play/p/1vQgD68KDsw)

Answer (score 3):

The other answer points in the right direction but is rather imprecise. Also, as of Go 1.22 the type parameter proposal has been superseded by the official language specification.

The quotes relevant to this issue are found in the [Interface types](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Interface_types) section:

> The type set of a term of the form `~T` is the set of all types whose underlying type is `T`

And:

> The type `T` in a term of the form `T` or `~T` cannot be a type parameter

Therefore when you define a type parameter list as (removing `Out` to simplify):

```
func demo[S ~In, In any](s S, in In) any
```

The constraint `~In` uses the tilde token with a type parameter, which is `In`, thus failing to compile. What is the constraint of `In` here is irrelevant.

Whereas with:

```
demo[S ~[]In, In any](s S, in In) any
```

The constraint `~[]In` instead uses the tilde token with **an unnamed slice literal** — i.e. `[]In` — which is *not* a type parameter, despite structurally referring to a type parameter.

That works because it meets this requirement:

> In a term of the form ~T, the underlying type of T must be itself, and T cannot be an interface.

And the [underlying type](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Underlying_types) of a type literal such as `[]In` is, in fact, itself:

> Each type T has an underlying type: If T is one of the predeclared boolean, numeric, or string types, **or a type literal**, the corresponding underlying type is T itself.